# HP Pavilion touch pad won't cut n paste

Tags: touchpad, hp, 18.04, paste

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Pavilion 15aw094nr and used firefox and chromium browsers and cut n paste won't work and I suspect it is the track/touch pad. When I highlight anything in a browser and tap the lower right cornet the highlight fails and cut n paste action doesn't occur. I can do other functions such as cursor and two finger scroll.

UPDATE ONE: Took machine back to U-MATE-16 and Cut-N-Paste as well as word check works by pressing lower right of pad. Although two-finger scroll does not but one finger scroll along right edge functions. So a shout out to the Ubuntu Gods, mash these two OS's together! LOL Right now I have only one machine so it's mission critical to me to have something that works, I'll maybe try U-18 in a fews months to see if this bug is fixed, and I might try U-MATE-18 in a few weeks which will be interesting to see if these functions still work.